# ValueError: `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 1000)). Found array with shape: (1, 3)

Tags: keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxpUn.png)

I've been Google for a long time, but they don't ask me the same questions as I do. They use a ready-made model. I'm a self-trained model, but I'm puzzled by the same mistakes.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2099607). Instead paste the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [`decode_predictions`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/6df456f59069c5daa752cbeef2b4f3a63c8874c1/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L198), expect that the number of classes to be 1000 (i.e. the number of classes in ImageNet dataset). Whereas it seems your custom model have only 3 output classes:

> `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array
>   of shape `(samples, 1000)`). Found array with shape: `(1, 3)`.